# Need to enable camera for the iframe/embed URL on WIX, but camera not getting enabled on WIX iframe/Embed

Tags: iframe, camera, embed, getusermedia, velo

on Wix, I want to understand How to enable camera for the iframe or embed URL. The URL that I am passing opens camera in browser and tested, but I want to know how to enable camera in WIX page, even I tried all the options available over WIX, but no luck.

Or Any service/plugins on wix which help us here to open camera functionality?, so we can use this service/plugin to enable camera to make work our Iframe/EMbed URL.

(Note: Our Iframe/Embed URL which needs camera enabled.)

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock" src="https://webcamera.io/" width=100% height=100%>
</iframe>

<script>

   var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe"); // finds all iframes

   for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {

      //var name = iframes[i].getAttribute("name")



          // I assume all html widgets we add through wix have "htmlComp" in their name

         iframes[i].setAttribute("allow", "microphone; camera")



}
```

Comment: Per se, you can't add native webcam support to the page according to https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-webcam-feed however it should be no problem by provide the webcam stream over the HTML APP: https://de.wix.com/app-market/html-iframe-embed/overview
Sorry second link could be german, just translate it quick and check if its working

Comment: @joshii_h it shows app is not availble, pls check the link again

Comment: did you try to add the functionality using a custom element? this does not use an iframe so it might be working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Wix doesn't allow camera access because it's a significant revenue stream for them. If you want to use the camera, you need to create a marketplace application. This means you'll be sharing a large portion of your profits with Wix. So, the short answer - it is currently not possible.

There is a feature request to enable camera access, https://www.wix.com/velo/requested-feature/camera-access, but it's been pending for 3 years now.